# How to use URI instead of resID while sampling images from large bitmap?

Tags: android

My app was throwing out of memory exception while loading 21 megapixel images as bitmap in my imageView.

```
Uri imageUri = /* URI goes here */
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
Imageview iv = (Imageview) findViewById (R.id.my_img_view);
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

so I found this page in official android documentation [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). which downsamples the image and loads a smaller version in memory rather than loading the whole image.

The problem is this code utilizes a ResID instead of a URI.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

How can I use this code with the URI I already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)` instead of `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(...)`:

```
    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```